# Connecting django app to postgres container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm having difficulty to connect my Django container app to my Postgres container.  The docker compose statement for the Postgres app is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./database.env # configure postgres
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down

volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
  
networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

The compose statement for the Django app is as follows:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
               python manage.py migrate &&
               python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
    ports:
      - 10555:8000
    environment:
      aws_access_key_id: ${aws_access_key_id}
      aws_secret_access_key: ${aws_secret_access_key}

networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

The difficulty emerges when performing the docker compose up statement.  I have attempted a number of different POSTGRES_HOST values (note they are successfully retrieved from Amazon Secrets Manager). I receive the following log output:

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container app  Created                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
Attaching to app
app  | /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
app  | 
app  |   warnings.warn(
app  | No changes detected
app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
app  |     self.connect()
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
app  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
app  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
app  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
app  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
app  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
app  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
app  | 
app  | 
app  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
app  | 
app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
app  |     main()
app  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
app  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
app  |     utility.execute()
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
app  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
app  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
app  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
app  |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
app  |     self.check(databases=[database])
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
app  |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
app  |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
app  |     errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1307, in check
app  |     *cls._check_indexes(databases),
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1699, in _check_indexes
app  |     connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
app  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 84, in is_postgresql_11
app  |     return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
app  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 339, in pg_version
app  |     with self.temporary_connection():
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
app  |     return next(self.gen)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 614, in temporary_connection
app  |     with self.cursor() as cursor:
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
app  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in cursor
app  |     return self._cursor()
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 246, in _cursor
app  |     self.ensure_connection()
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
app  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in ensure_connection
app  |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
app  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
app  |     self.connect()
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
app  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
app  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
app  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
app  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
app  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
app  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
app  | 
app exited with code 1
```

I'm at a loss.  What POSTGRES_HOST value should I be using?  Should I be establishing the network settings differently?

Comment: Because you have 2 docker-compose files, you get 2 separate networks. Put the database and the app service in the same compose file to get them on the same network. When you do that, you can connect to the database using the service name as the host name, i.e. 'database'.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing them in a single file because I want to establish and maintain them separately.  I will do this if I must.  But I am hoping that the networks can be linked without creating a single compose file.  Thank you.

Comment: Try `database` as the Postgres hostname as that's how your service is called in the docker-compose file.

Comment: When you have both containers running, if you do `docker network ls` you should see two networks with names ending in 'djangonetwork'. You can get the containers to hook up to the same network, but then you have to define the networks as `external` and create the network manually before starting the containers using `docker network create`.

Comment: I had to clean up old legacy networks.  Creating the network manually and then joining it as "external" from each was successful.  I will paste my new yaml scripts below.  Thanks fr your help.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the network manually and then utilizing an external join for each independent container was successful.  Script to start network in shell:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge dbnet
```

Revised Postgres yaml (note that I modified the port setting in this version to simplify):

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./database.env # configure postgres
    networks:
      - dbnet
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down

volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose

networks:
  dbnet:
    external: true
```

Revised Django yaml script:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
               python manage.py migrate &&
               python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    networks:
      - dbnet
    ports:
      - 10555:8000
    environment:
      aws_access_key_id: ${aws_access_key_id}
      aws_secret_access_key: ${aws_secret_access_key}

networks:
  dbnet:
    external: true
```